# Multiple parametes between same Slash route

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to pass 2 parameters between the same slash, if i use one parameter it works fine, but 2 is not working.

Example:
route:

```
Works:
Route::get('/jobpost-{title}','SomeController@show')->name('name.route');

Don't works:
Route::get('/jobpost-{title}-day-{day}','SomeController@showMore')->name('name.route.other');
```

I notice that if i add a slash before the parameter day it works fine, but i need to find a way (beside creating a slug column) to be able to have 2 parameters in same route.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could just change the order of your routes:

```
Route::get('/jobpost-{title}-day-{day}','SomeController@showMore')
    ->name('name.route.other');
Route::get('/jobpost-{title}','SomeController@show')
    ->name('name.route');
```

Alternatively, change the signature of your route with `title` and `day`:

```
Route::get('/jobpost/{title}/day/{day}','SomeController@showMore')
    ->name('name.route.other');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to define two variables between two slashes. you must do some regular expression to get what you want. something like this :

```
Route::get('/jobpost-{complex}',function(Request $request, $complex){
    $pattern = '/(.*)-day-(.*)/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $complex, $matches);

    $title = $matches[1];
    $day = $matches[2];
    return SomeController::showMore($request, $title, $day);
})->where('complex', '(.*)-day-(.*)');
```

---

update:
look like you can have multiple variables inside two slashes.

so as @Unflux said you must do priority with changing routes order.

Comment: you can have multiple route parameters in a single segment

Answer (score 0):

--

it's work like that

you have to pass the parameters this way

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {
    return view('index',['name'=>$name,'id'=>$id]);
});
```